# XML event filter based on weekday and time

Tags: xml, syntax, event-viewer, eventfilter

I am trying to set a custom event filter where day is between Monday-Friday and time is between 8am-5pm

```
*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime &gt;='T08:00:00' and @SystemTime &lt;='T17:00:00']]]
```

I am new to XML and will appreciate any help/guidance.